# Xamarin.Forms/Android GoogleSignInAPI login stuck loading after some time

Tags: android, firebase, forms, xamarin, google-signin

I've been wanting to add Google O Authentication to my Xamarin.Forms App and the Xamarin.Android part is causing trouble.
Based on a YouTube tutorial, I included the needed libraries and included the necessary code (see below).

For the API, I use Google Firebase and Google Cloud Platform (needed to get my API keys).
When installing my App onto a device, regardless of physical or emulated, the SignIn-Process works just fine for the next 3-5 days. I can choose a google account and be authenticated.
However, [the login screen will be stuck loading after that time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIFpG.png)

Sometimes, not often, the API will return

> Status{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null} (please read below what I've tried)

**Libraries I use for the process:**

> using Android.Gms.Auth.Api;

> using Android.Gms.Auth.Api.SignIn;

> using Android.Gms.Common;

> using Android.Gms.Common.Apis;

> using Android.OS;

**Expected behavior:**

As always, the Google Sign-In popup comes up and either auto logs the user in (in case they've already chosen an account in the past) or shows the available accounts and continues to authenticate the user.
[This is how it should look like, sorry for the German](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRizG.png)
**What is wrong:**

The sign-in view does pop up, though it just keeps on loading. Only reinstalling the entire app will help to fix it.

**What I've tried:**

As mentioned above, I do sometimes get

> Status{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}

returned.
I already researched this error and found out that an invalid or not existing SHA1 key for my android app might be the cause.
I checked on Firebase and both my Debug and Release Keystore are added.

**What is mentionable:**

- The login procedure always goes when starting the app. Regardless if logged in or not. This could be a cause, but I don't know what alternative I should use. Perhaps store IdToken and use it until it expired?
- I request both Email and IdToken for the sake of verifying the user serverside.
- I use *Android.Gms.Common.Apis* which is deprecated

**GoogleManager.cs**

```
public class GoogleManager : Java.Lang.Object, IGoogleManager, GoogleApiClient.IConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.IOnConnectionFailedListener
    {
        public Action<GoogleUser, string> _onLoginComplete;
        public static GoogleApiClient _googleApiClient { get; set; }
        public static GoogleManager Instance { get; private set; }
        Context _context;

        public GoogleManager()
        {
            _context = global::Android.App.Application.Context;
            Instance = this;
        }

        public void Login(Action<GoogleUser, string> onLoginComplete)
        {
            GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DefaultSignIn).RequestIdToken("my_stuff.apps.googleusercontent.com")
                                                             .RequestEmail()
                                                             .Build();
            _googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder((_context).ApplicationContext)
                .AddConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .AddOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .AddApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .AddScope(new Scope(Scopes.Profile))
                .Build();

            _onLoginComplete = onLoginComplete;
            Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.GetSignInIntent(_googleApiClient);
            ((MainActivity)Forms.Context).StartActivityForResult(signInIntent, 1);
            _googleApiClient.Connect();
        }

        public void Logout()
        {
            var gsoBuilder = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DefaultSignIn).RequestEmail();

            GoogleSignIn.GetClient(_context, gsoBuilder.Build())?.SignOut();

            _googleApiClient.Disconnect();

        }

        public void OnAuthCompleted(GoogleSignInResult result)
        {
            if (result.IsSuccess)
            {
                GoogleSignInAccount accountt = result.SignInAccount;
                _onLoginComplete?.Invoke(new GoogleUser()
                {
                    Name = accountt.GivenName,
                    Email = accountt.Email,
                    ID = accountt.Id,
                    IdToken = accountt.IdToken,
                }, string.Empty);
            }
            else
            {
                _onLoginComplete?.Invoke(null, AppResources.error_this_didnt_work_text);
            }
        }

        public void OnConnected(Bundle connectionHint)
        {

        }

        public void OnConnectionSuspended(int cause)
        {
            _onLoginComplete?.Invoke(null, "Canceled!");
        }

        public void OnConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result)
        {
            _onLoginComplete?.Invoke(null, result.ErrorMessage);
        }
```

**OnActivityResult from MainActivity.cs**

```
        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Android.Content.Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == 1)
            {
                GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.GetSignInResultFromIntent(data);
                Console.WriteLine("LOGIN RESULT" + result.Status + result.SignInAccount);
                GoogleManager.Instance.OnAuthCompleted(result);
            }
        }
```

Hopefully, someone has an answer. Let me know if there is anything you need to know

Comment: Is there any logs about this problem?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT unfortunately, there is nothing being logged besides "Status{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null}" which only appeares sometimes..

Comment: I have gave my answer, you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

If you get error code 8 (`INTERNAL_ERROR`), please double check your app registration in dev console. Note that every registered Android client is uniquely identified by the (package name, Android Signing Certificate SHA-1) pair. If you have multiple package names / signing certificate for your debug and production environments, make sure to register every pair of them. To verify:

1. Open the [Credentials page](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector2/projectselector/apis/credentials?pli=1&supportedpurview=project&folder=true&organizationId=true) and select your project
2. Make sure
   every pair has an Android typed OAuth 2.0 client IDs. To create a
   new OAuth 2.0 client ID for your Android client, select `New Credentials`->`OAuth2 Client ID` from the dropdown, select Android and
   input your Package name / Signing-certificate fingerprint there.

To get your signing key certificate SHA-1:

**Standard Debug Key**

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

**Other (Custom) Key**

```
keytool -list -v -keystore $YOUR_KEYSTORE_LOCATION
```